# The "catalog.leftnav" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered

Tags: magento2

On Magento 2.4.2 front-end checkout page I get a blank screen.

EXCEPTION LOG SAYS:

```
The "catalog.leftnav" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The \"catalog.leftnav\" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. at vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/ExceptionHandlerBlock.php:59)
```

CHECKOUT PAGE VIEW SOURCE SAYS:

```
    
        
            
        
    
    var elempr6XFJZf = document.querySelector('#checkout-loader img');
if (elempr6XFJZf) {
elempr6XFJZf.style.position = 'absolute';
}    
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#checkout": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.
```

Comment: Why "catalog.leftnav" in the checkout page

Comment: I'm not sure why there is a "catalog.leftnav" on the checkout page.  But I figured out the issue.  This happened after a Magento 1.9x migration to 2.4.2.  The migration brought over some module and related settings.  I turned off all shipping and payment modules and one by one turned them back on to find the offending module -- then all good.

Answer (score 0):

A Magento migration from 1.9x to 2.4.2 brought over a shipping module and related settings. I turned off all shipping and payment modules and then one by one turned them back on to find the offending module -- then simply turned off the unwanted offending migrated shipping module.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar error. Not solved.
Turn modules off and on does not solve my case.
From my exception log:

main.CRITICAL: The "catalog.leftnav" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(code: 0): The "catalog.leftnav" block threw an exception, and it can't be rendered. at /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/ExceptionHandlerBlock.php:59)"}

Comment: Please don't ask questions in the answers section.